# Exact strings in a column in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to use mysql to solve the question below.

Any idea how should I make it work? Thank you.

Tried to use the code below but extracted duplicate strings in two columns and it's hard-code so it's not working..

```
SELECT itemid, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(item_variation, ',', 1), ',', -1) 'type one',
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(item_variation, ',', 2), ',', -1) 'type two',
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(item_variation, ',', 3), ',', -1) 'type three',
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(item_variation, ',', 4), ',', -1) 'type four'
FROM data
```

#### Question:

To extract items with more than 3 types

```
|itemid|shopid|item_name|item_type|price|stock|creation_date|
|1|10000|clothes|{}|5|100|27/1/2018|
|2|10000|dress|{Pink: 20, Black: 20, Grey: 20}|20|100|20/2/2018|
|3|10001|t-shirt|{S: 2, M: 2, L: 2, XL: 2}|2|50|1/1/2018|
|4|10002|socks|{us5.5: 1, us9: 1, us4.5: 1, us10: 1, us7: 1, us6: 1, us5: 1}|1|1000|4/1/2018|
|5|10002|Gloves|{S: 2, M: 2}|2|500|6/1/2018|
```

#### Expected result

```
|itemid |item_name  |item_type|
|3      |t-shirt    |{S: 2, M: 2, L: 2, XL: 2}|
|4      |socks      |{us5.5: 1, us9: 1, us4.5: 1, us10: 1, us7: 1, us6: 1, us5: 1}|
```

Comment: Please show the exact SQL statement you tried, not a fragment of it.

Comment: Hi @kmoser, please check on my update.

Comment: What's the datatype of Item_type column?

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur it's varchar

Comment: my answer will serve your purpose if there is no other comma other than separator. You can use this code for any string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ought to do:

```
select itemid, item_name, item_type
from t
where length(item_type) - length(replace(item_type, ',', '')) >= 3;
```

You need a special case to tell 0 and 1 apart.  It would not work if item_type contains ',' in either key or value of the json-like field (missing quoted around strings to be json).

Answer (score 1):

You just need to count number of comma(,)>=3. Try below code:

```
SELECT 
    Itemid,Item_Name,Item_type
      
FROM myjson 
where ROUND (   
        (
            LENGTH(item_type)
            - LENGTH( REPLACE ( item_type, ",", "") ) 
        ) / LENGTH(",")        
    )>=3
```